# Can't configure SSL connection between Spring Boot and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, ssl

I want to configure SSL on Postgresql 12. Then my Java application will add entries to the database, delete, etc.

I created certificates: CA, server, client. 
CA and server are located in the directory C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data 
The client is located in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\postgresql.

I made this to my Java (truststore): https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html

**Configs:**

pg_hba:

```
hostnossl     all          all            0.0.0.0/0                reject
hostssl       all          all           0.0.0.0/0            cert clientcert=1
```

postgresql.conf:

```
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
```

I can connect server throw pgAdmin and cmd with my certificates, but I can't connect throw my Spring Boot Application.

Now there is this application.propperties:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=classpath:postgresql.jks
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=111111
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/usersmanagement?ssl=true&sslmode=require&sslrootcert='root.crt'

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=111111
```

When I ran my app I get:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Received fatal alert:
>   unexpected_message

It happens at the end of process, as I see(the part of javax.net.debug=ssl results):

```
update handshake state: change_cipher_spec
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 104, 228, 110, 105, 172, 1, 108, 84, 30, 158, 127, 133 }
***
update handshake state: finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, unexpected_message
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
```

Logs of PostgreSQL says nothing new:

> MESSAGE: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

I really don't know what can be wrong... Maybe somebody here can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: As I have been seen thriw debuggin this exception is thrown by this line in PgConnection.class:
this.queryExecutor = ConnectionFactory.openConnection(hostSpecs, user, database, info);

Comment: found this in RUN:
X509KeyManager passed to SSLContext.init():  need an X509ExtendedKeyManager for SSLEngine use

Comment: I DID IT!
But now Hikari shutdowns application after connections on the load step. If anyone know what can be wrong, I would be lucky to know.
Also I'll write how I did my ssl connection in steps here as an answer.